# Preventing starving in node.js apps

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

I am very new to `node.js` and i was quite impressed by the asynchronous event-loop based execution pattern used by it and the results it can achieve in real-time web applications. I understand that since `node.js` is single threaded, the only way it can utilize the parallelism available with multi-core CPUs is to spawn a new instance one for every core, (the approach used by the `Cluster` for `node.js` ), which I believe is not true parallelism. However now I am interested in a different question:

Assuming I have such a setup where I run one instance in each available CPU core, how can I effectively ensure that the exclusive locks that the application uses does not cause any starving? What are the guidelines to be followed, best practices if any, and any other help in this matter is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It achieves parallelism by putting all I/O async (costly part).  Everything *does* run in parallel except your code.  http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your statement. But concurrency and not true parallelism was the target of node developers. True parallelism is what Apache server achieves and we know the problem with that (multithreading). Cluster was added to take advantage of multi-core CPUs available.

To answer your question node uses round-robin scheduler (see this [commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/e72cd41)). It distributes the incoming requests one-by-one to each worker. Regarding locking, workers will be utilized best if they run parallely. In a server each worker functions independent of other. If you need locking, make sure they don't sit idle.